# Jmeter recording feature capture different URL than what is provided in HTTPS domain

Tags: jmeter

Whenever I try to use `Jmeter` recording functionality for the website, the requests send to website are captured but the name of website is different and body data is encrypted.

`Jmeter` always shows request for : `ocsp.comodoca.com`, `ocsp.digicert.com`, `ocsp.pki.goog`. But these are not the URLs provided for HTTPS Domains in Test Script Recorder.

I checked on the Internet that `ocsp.comodoca.com`, `ocsp.digicert.com`, `ocsp.pki.goog` provide SSL certificate. But why those are seen in `Jmeter` request are not known to me and how to see the URL for my test website? Thanks.

[HTTPS Test Script recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd2mz.jpg)
[Junk Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj9xY.jpg)

Comment: Hey @AlexSergeenko, did you find out the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue while recording with JMeter. I later found the issue had to do with the way I had setup the proxy options in Firefox.

I had forgotten to select the check box `Use this proxy server for all protocols. After selecting this check box, I was able to record my actual server URLs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking into wrong feature, the setting you should be using lives at `Requests filtering` tab of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

There is "URL Patterns to Exclude" input where you can filter out "not interesting" domains by providing a [Perl-5-style regular expression](https://www.pcre.org/), i.e. `.*ocsp.*`

[image: JMeter Filter Requests]

See [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) article for more details if needed

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. The issue is that if I have provided 'xyz.com' in HTTPS Domains in 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder' screen, Jmeter does not capture request for that url. Instead it captures requests from ocsp.comodoca.com, ocsp.digicert.com, ocsp.pki.goog. The test website is hosted on AWS cloud.

Comment: Hey @FriendNeed. Did you find out the answer?

Comment: No. I had to use other methods for creating JMeter scripts.